# VSCode: Remote SSH - Socket connection failed

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code, ssh, vscode-extensions, vscode-remote

My connection using the commands `ssh root@ip_address` and `sftp root@ip_address` in a bash terminal is successful.
But, the VSCode addon *Remote SSH* produces an error anytime I attempt to connect through SSH `"Failed to set up socket for dynamic port forward to remote port 34223: Socket closed. Is the remote port correct?"`

Extension output log is:

```
[19:16:58.110] Log Level: 2
[19:16:58.122] SSH Resolver called for "ssh-remote+7b22686f73744e616d65223a2238392e3131372e33362e3235222c2275736572223a22726f6f74227d", attempt 1
[19:16:58.123] "remote.SSH.showLoginTerminal": false
[19:16:58.125] "remote.SSH.path": undefined
[19:16:58.125] "remote.SSH.configFile": undefined
[19:16:58.125] "remote.SSH.useFlock": true
[19:16:58.126] "remote.SSH.lockfilesInTmp": false
[19:16:58.126] "remote.SSH.localServerDownload": auto
[19:16:58.127] "remote.SSH.remoteServerListenOnSocket": false
[19:16:58.127] "remote.SSH.showLoginTerminal": false
[19:16:58.127] "remote.SSH.defaultExtensions": []
[19:16:58.128] "remote.SSH.loglevel": 2
[19:16:58.130] "remote.SSH.enableDynamicForwarding": true
[19:16:58.130] "remote.SSH.enableRemoteCommand": false
[19:16:58.130] "remote.SSH.serverPickPortsFromRange": {}
[19:16:58.131] "remote.SSH.serverInstallPath": {}
[19:16:58.136] VS Code version: 1.76.0
[19:16:58.136] Remote-SSH version: remote-ssh@0.98.0
[19:16:58.136] linux x64
[19:16:58.137] SSH Resolver called for host: root@89.117.36.25
[19:16:58.138] Setting up SSH remote "89.117.36.25"
[19:16:58.141] Using commit id "92da9481c0904c6adfe372c12da3b7748d74bdcb" and quality "stable" for server
[19:16:58.145] Install and start server if needed
[19:17:02.874] PATH: /home/imran/.nvm/versions/node/v16.19.0/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/snap/bin
[19:17:02.875] Checking ssh with "ssh -V"
[19:17:02.883] > OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.1, OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022

[19:17:02.886] Running script with connection command: ssh -T -D 42117 -o ConnectTimeout=15 'root@89.117.36.25' bash
[19:17:07.428] > 20aaf2b3d4d3: running
[19:17:07.428] Got some output, clearing connection timeout
[19:17:07.455] > Acquiring lock on /root/.vscode-server/bin/92da9481c0904c6adfe372c12da3b7748d74bdcb/vscode-remote-lock.root.92da9481c0904c6adfe372c12da3b7748d74bdcb
[19:17:07.463] > Found existing installation at /root/.vscode-server/bin/92da9481c0904c6adfe372c12da3b7748d74bdcb...
> Checking /root/.vscode-server/.92da9481c0904c6adfe372c12da3b7748d74bdcb.log and /root/.vscode-server/.92da9481c0904c6adfe372c12da3b7748d74bdcb.pid for a running server
> Looking for server with pid: 22448
[19:17:07.474] > Running ssh connection command... /root/.vscode-server/bin/92da9481c0904c6adfe372c12da3b7748d74bdcb/bin/code-server --start-server --host=127.0.0.1 --accept-server-license-terms --enable-remote-auto-shutdown --port=0 --telemetry-level all   &> "/root/.vscode-server/.92da9481c0904c6adfe372c12da3b7748d74bdcb.log" < /dev/null
> printenv:
>     LC_MEASUREMENT=bn_BD
>     SSH_CONNECTION=182.160.105.186 51684 89.117.36.25 22
>     LC_PAPER=bn_BD
>     LC_MONETARY=bn_BD
>     LANG=en_US.UTF-8
>     LC_NAME=bn_BD
>     USER=root
>     PWD=/root
>     HOME=/root
>     SSH_CLIENT=182.160.105.186 51684 22
>     LC_ADDRESS=bn_BD
>     LC_NUMERIC=bn_BD
>     MAIL=/var/mail/root
>     SHELL=/bin/bash
>     SHLVL=2
>     LC_TELEPHONE=bn_BD
>     VSCODE_AGENT_FOLDER=/root/.vscode-server
>     LOGNAME=root
>     PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
>     LC_IDENTIFICATION=bn_BD
>     LC_TIME=bn_BD
>     _=/usr/bin/printenv
[19:17:07.480] > Removing old logfile at /root/.vscode-server/.92da9481c0904c6adfe372c12da3b7748d74bdcb.log
> Spawned remote server: 22553
> cat: /root/.vscode-server/.92da9481c0904c6adfe372c12da3b7748d74bdcb.log: No such file or directory
[19:17:07.739] > Waiting for server log...
> Waiting for server log...
>  
> *
> * Visual Studio Code Server
> *
> * By using the software, you agree to
> * the Visual Studio Code Server License Terms (https://aka.ms/vscode-server-license) and
> * the Microsoft Privacy Statement (https://privacy.microsoft.com/en-US/privacystatement).
> *
>  
> 20aaf2b3d4d3: start
> SSH_AUTH_SOCK====
> DISPLAY====
> webUiAccessToken====
> listeningOn==37949==
> osReleaseId==ubuntu==
> arch==x86_64==
> tmpDir==/tmp==
> platform==linux==
> unpackResult====
> didLocalDownload==0==
> downloadTime====
> installTime====
> extInstallTime====
> serverStartTime==84==
> connectionToken==1111a11a-1a11-111a-a111-11111a1111aa==
> 20aaf2b3d4d3: end
[19:17:07.739] Received install output: 
SSH_AUTH_SOCK====
DISPLAY====
webUiAccessToken====
listeningOn==37949==
osReleaseId==ubuntu==
arch==x86_64==
tmpDir==/tmp==
platform==linux==
unpackResult====
didLocalDownload==0==
downloadTime====
installTime====
extInstallTime====
serverStartTime==84==
connectionToken==1111a11a-1a11-111a-a111-11111a1111aa==

[19:17:07.740] Remote server is listening on 37949
[19:17:07.740] Parsed server configuration: {"serverConfiguration":{"remoteListeningOn":{"port":37949},"osReleaseId":"ubuntu","arch":"x86_64","webUiAccessToken":"","sshAuthSock":"","display":"","tmpDir":"/tmp","platform":"linux","connectionToken":"1111a11a-1a11-111a-a111-11111a1111aa"},"serverStartTime":84,"installUnpackCode":""}
[19:17:07.742] Starting forwarding server. localPort 34863 -> socksPort 42117 -> remotePort 37949
[19:17:07.743] Forwarding server listening on 34863
[19:17:07.743] Waiting for ssh tunnel to be ready
[19:17:07.744] [Forwarding server 34863] Got connection 0
[19:17:07.745] Tunneled 37949 to local port 34863
[19:17:07.745] Resolved "ssh-remote+7b22686f73744e616d65223a2238392e3131372e33362e3235222c2275736572223a22726f6f74227d" to "127.0.0.1:34863"
[19:17:07.755] ------




[19:17:07.815] [Forwarding server 34863] Got connection 1
[19:17:08.033] Failed to set up socket for dynamic port forward to remote port 37949: Socket closed. Is the remote port correct?
[19:17:08.041] > channel 3: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
[19:17:08.099] Failed to set up socket for dynamic port forward to remote port 37949: Socket closed. Is the remote port correct?
[19:17:08.105] > channel 4: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
```

In my server **ssh_config** file, I configured **AllowTcpForwarding true**.  I also tried with **remote.SSH.useLocalServer": false**. But still getting errors. Can you please help?

Answer (score 0):

It seems your remote server does not allow TCP forwarding.

Make sure /etc/ssh/sshd_config contains :

```
AllowTcpForwarding yes
```

Comment: I configured. But still don't work

Comment: Have you restarted ssh daemon or server machine after changing the configuration parameter ?

Comment: I restarted, but nothing changed. Finally I found a solution that my vscode-server on server machine doesn't worked properly. I looked at the error log and fixed errors. And it works properly.

Comment: Can you post your solution as an answer?

Comment: @MdJahidKhanLimon please post your solution as an answer. This issue seems to affect lots of people